# Reading ith structure from a binary file in C

Tags: c, file, binary, structure

I have some binary file that i write struct objects to(of one defined type). I want to be able to read particular (ith) "struct block" from a binary file to a struct and display it. The only idea that comes to my mind is to create an array of structures containning all of them so that i could have an access to the ordinary one but it doesn't seem to be an efficient way.
I would appreciate if one could help me with this problem :)

Comment: If you've written code that can successfully write structs to a file, then you have the ability to at least make an effort at this. We're not a code writing service.

Comment: Since you know the size of each structure it should be very easy.

Comment: When you are writing your example to post, consider a file offset of `(ith - 1) * sizeof (struct yourstruct)`.

Comment: Carey Gregory: Where did i ask to write code for me? I just ask for explainning procedure. I don't know how to use fread function for this purpose since there is no pointer specifier to refer to particular position in file.

Answer (score 3):

I am [new to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282076/getting-a-segmentation-fault-while-trying-to-write-a-struct-instance-to-a-file/30282121#30282121) but think I can help with this.  Is this the kind of thing you were looking to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//just a struct for purposes of demonstration
struct my_struct{
  int prop1;
  int prop2;
};

//writes structs to filename.dat
void writeStruct(int property){
  FILE *file_pointer;
  file_pointer = fopen("filename.dat","ab");

  //define and assign variables to a quick dummy struct
  struct my_struct this_struct;
  this_struct.prop1=property;
  this_struct.prop2=property*2;

  //write struct to file
  fwrite(&this_struct, sizeof(this_struct), 1, file_pointer);
  fclose(file_pointer);
}

//returns the nth struct stored in "filename.dat"
struct my_struct getNthStruct(long int n){
  FILE *file_pointer;
  file_pointer = fopen("filename.dat","rb");

  //will be the struct we retrieve from the file
  struct my_struct nth_struct;

  //set read position of file to nth struct instance in file
  fseek(file_pointer, n*sizeof(struct my_struct), SEEK_SET);

  //copy specified struct instance to the 'nth_struct' variable
  fread(&nth_struct, sizeof(struct my_struct), 1, file_pointer);

  return nth_struct;
}

int main(){
  //write a bunch of structs to a file
  writeStruct(1);
  writeStruct(2);
  writeStruct(3);
  writeStruct(4);
  writeStruct(5);

  //get nth struct (2 is third struct, in this case)
  struct my_struct nth_struct;
  nth_struct=getNthStruct(2);

  printf("nth_struct.prop1=%d, nth_struct.prop2=%d\n",
      nth_struct.prop1, //outputs 3
      nth_struct.prop2); //outputs 6

  return 0;
}
```

I intentionally didn't check for obvious errors (FILE pointers returning `NULL`, length of files, etc) for brevity and isolating the core concept.

**Feedback is welcome.**

Comment: Except for the absence of error handling, which you explicitly mention, what you've got works nicely for simple structures with a fixed size and no pointers.  Life gets trickier if you have to deal with variable size structures, or the structures contain pointers instead of, say, fixed size arrays.  Structures using a FAM (flexible array member) are also problematic because they too are not a fixed size.  Such issues can be dealt with; it requires a _lot_ more code to do so.

Comment: One change worth thinking about is combining declaration with initialization. For example, you could replace: `FILE *file_pointer; file_pointer = fopen("filename.dat","rb");` (2 statements) with `FILE *file_pointer = fopen("filename.dat","rb");` (1 statement).  That works in C89. Similarly, you could replace `struct my_struct this_struct; this_struct.prop1=property; this_struct.prop2=property*2;` (3 statements) with `struct my_struct this_struct = { property, property*2 };` (C89) or even `struct my_struct this_struct = { .prop1 = property, .prop2 = property*2 };` (C99 designated initializers).